# How to continue program after closing tkinter-window?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have a problem with two tkinter windows which I simplified as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

def function_2(): # creates Window 2
    root2 = tk.Tk()
    # some buttons targeting other functions
    root2.mainloop()
    print(1) # just a placeholder for some other code

def function_1(): # creates Window 1
    root = tk.Tk()
    funtcion_2()
    root.mainloop()

function_1()
```

I want the `print(1)` in `function_2` to be executed after I close window 2, which is created in `function_2`, manually by clicking the X in the upper right corner of a Windows window. However the output "1" won't show up as long as I don't close window 1 as well.
What shall I do to get the desired result?

I already tried threading because I thought the code in `function_2` seems to 'wait' until everything in `function_1` is executed.
I also tried

```
root2.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: root2.destroy())
```

underneath the line

```
root2 = tk.Tk()
```

in `function_2`. But the result is the same: I don't return to `function_1` after closing window 2.

Comment: That print should already be executed before the function1's mainloop, so I assume it could be buffering issue? Print is not flushing by default (although usually something else triggers the flushing). Try `print(1, flush=True)`

Comment: @h4z3 thanks for your comment but even if this works, the "print(1)" command is just an example for some other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that `mainloop()` should be called once.  Also avoid using multiple instances of `Tk()`.

For your case, use `root2.wait_window()` instead of `root2.mainloop()`:

```py
def function2(): # creates Window 2
    root2 = tk.Tk()
    # some buttons targeting other functions
    root2.wait_window() # wait for closing of root2
    print(1)
```

Note that there are typos in your code:

- `function_1()` should be `function1()` or vice versa
- `function_2()` should be `function2()` or vice versa

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! I fixed the typos, thanks for mentioning.
What should I do instead of using multiple instances of Tk()? How can I create multiple windows in a nicer way? And whats wrong with this in the first place?

Comment: See [why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)